# A field only visible when a node is being edited

Tags: 8

I have a custom field which should be only visible when a node (an article) is being edited (and not shown when a new content is created). I'd like to avoid installing a module for this, so my question is if there might be a specific configuration setting for this in the core itself?

Comment: You would have to do a form alter for this.

Comment: There is no configuration for this, do what Kevin said.

Comment: Yes, there is no configuration in core. Another option is using different form modes, which you can configure in core, but not control when they are used. For this you need a module like https://www.drupal.org/project/form_mode_control